# Selecting by datetime field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

```
Select col1 FROM mytable WHERE ValidUntil > 7/9/2009 8:45:30 pm
```

and the error is `Incorrect syntax near '8'.`

So what is wrong with this sql statement?

I tried this directly on SQL management studio...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select col1 FROM mytable WHERE ValidUntil > '7/9/2009 8:45:30 pm'
```

Be aware that it all depend on the collation of your column. If the collation is latin french, for example, the 'pm' will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm-dd' format is working with all collations. Try not to use am / pm. It is better to use 24-hour format.